# How to merge two Pandas Dataframes based on a shared column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data coming in from multiple measurement sources using timestamps and need to merge them all into a single Dataframe.

Here's an example of the incoming Dataframes:

Dataframe A

```
Datetime              A      B
2023-05-21 18:00:00   1.5    1.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00   1.6    1.6
2023-05-21 18:02:00   1.7    1.6
2023-05-21 18:04:00   1.5    1.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   1.6    1.5
```

Dataframe B

```
Datetime              C      D
2023-05-21 18:00:00   0.5    0.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00   0.6    0.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00   0.6    0.5
2023-05-21 18:04:00   0.5    0.6
2023-05-21 18:05:00   0.6    0.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   0.6    0.5
```

Dataframe C

```
Datetime              E      F
2023-05-21 18:00:00   2.5    2.6
2023-05-21 18:02:00   2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00   2.6    2.5
2023-05-21 18:05:00   2.6    2.6
2023-05-21 18:06:00   2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   2.6    2.5
```

And the resulting Dataframe I want is:

Dataframe Result

```
Datetime               A      B      C      D      E      F
2023-05-21 18:00:00    1.5    1.6    0.5    0.6    2.5    2.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00    1.6    1.6    0.6    0.6    NaN    NaN
2023-05-21 18:02:00    1.7    1.6    NaN    NaN    2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00    NaN    NaN    0.6    0.5    2.6    2.5
2023-05-21 18:04:00    1.5    1.6    0.5    0.6    NaN    NaN
2023-05-21 18:05:00    NaN    NaN    0.6    0.6    2.6    2.6
2023-05-21 18:06:00    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00    1.6    1.5    0.6    0.5    2.6    2.5
```

I've tried using concat and specifying axis=1 as well as a couple other things but I always end up with either multiple Datetime columns and way more rows than I want or I get errors when trying to merge if I set the index to Datetime prior to using concat.

Comment: What happens when you try `pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=1)` after setting your date as the index on all data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imports and `read_csv` code provided to be extra clear.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

a = '''Datetime              A      B
2023-05-21 18:00:00   1.5    1.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00   1.6    1.6
2023-05-21 18:02:00   1.7    1.6
2023-05-21 18:04:00   1.5    1.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   1.6    1.5'''

b = '''Datetime              C      D
2023-05-21 18:00:00   0.5    0.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00   0.6    0.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00   0.6    0.5
2023-05-21 18:04:00   0.5    0.6
2023-05-21 18:05:00   0.6    0.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   0.6    0.5'''

c = '''Datetime              E      F
2023-05-21 18:00:00   2.5    2.6
2023-05-21 18:02:00   2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00   2.6    2.5
2023-05-21 18:05:00   2.6    2.6
2023-05-21 18:06:00   2.7    2.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00   2.6    2.5'''
```

For this purpose, I need to impute a column separator only if there are more than two spaces. I also want to parse the `Datetime` column.

```
a = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(a), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=['Datetime'])
b = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(b), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=['Datetime'])
c = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(c), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=['Datetime'])
```

I set all the data frames to use the `Datetime` column as an index then concatenate them horizontally, then sort by the index:

```
>>> pd.concat([i.set_index('Datetime') for i in [a, b, c]], axis=1) \
...     .sort_index()
                       A    B    C    D    E    F
Datetime                                         
2023-05-21 18:00:00  1.5  1.6  0.5  0.6  2.5  2.6
2023-05-21 18:01:00  1.6  1.6  0.6  0.6  NaN  NaN
2023-05-21 18:02:00  1.7  1.6  NaN  NaN  2.7  2.6
2023-05-21 18:03:00  NaN  NaN  0.6  0.5  2.6  2.5
2023-05-21 18:04:00  1.5  1.6  0.5  0.6  NaN  NaN
2023-05-21 18:05:00  NaN  NaN  0.6  0.6  2.6  2.6
2023-05-21 18:06:00  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.7  2.6
2023-05-21 18:07:00  1.6  1.5  0.6  0.5  2.6  2.5
```